# Instantiating geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3 with proxies causes exception

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to call GoogleV3 geolocator like this:

```
geolocator = GoogleV3(proxies={"http": "http://user:password@ip:port"})
address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode('address to geocode')
```

and it raises:

```
AttributeError: OpenerDirector instance has no __call__ method
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in current implementation of GoogleV3 to pass user and password variables directly to urllib2.opener (GoogleV3 uses urllib2 behind the scenes).

Here is example how urllib2.opener should be called:

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', 'username', 'password')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
# This time, rather than install the OpenerDirector, we use it directly:
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

Sadly, but current GoogleV3 implementation does not use urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler .

So, you need to extend it by modifying source: https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/geocoders/base.py
On the top add:

from urlparse import urlparse

then find 'if self.proxies is None:' code and replace it with:

```
    if self.proxies is None:
        self.urlopen = urllib_urlopen
    else:
        params = urlparse(proxies[1])
        host = params.get('hostname')
        username = params.get('username')
        password = params.get('password')
        if host and username and password:
            proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
            proxy_auth_handler.add_password(None, host, username, password)
            self.urlopen = build_opener(
               ProxyHandler(self.proxies, proxy_auth_handler),
            )
```